# ID check on an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am having trouble for the past week trying to solve how to check if an Id has already been added to the array, and if it has, stop the user from entering the rest of the data, I would greatly appreciate some help with this.

My code:

```
class CustomerUse {
   public static int checkId(Customer theArray[], int noOfValues,
         String searchId) {
      int idCheck = 0;
      int step = 0;
      while (step < noOfValues) {
         step++;
         if ((step < noOfValues) && (theArray[step].getId().equals(searchId))) {
            idCheck = -1;
         }
      }
      return idCheck;
   }

   public static void listAllNames(Customer[] names, int NoOfElements) {
      int index;
      String result;
      for (index = 0; index < NoOfElements; index++) {
         System.out.println(names[index]);
      }
   }

   public static int findPlace(Customer theArray[], int balance, int noOfValues) {
      int step;
      int place;
      step = 0;
      while ((step < noOfValues) && (balance < theArray[step].getBalance())) {
         step++;
      }
      place = step;
      return place;
   }

   public static int addOne(Customer theArray[], int place, String Id,
         Customer theObject, int noOfValues) {
      int step;
      if (noOfValues == 0) {
         theArray[0] = theObject;
         noOfValues++;
      } else {
         for (step = noOfValues - 1; step >= place; step--) {
            theArray[step + 1] = theArray[step];
         }
         theArray[place] = theObject;
         noOfValues++;
      }
      return noOfValues;
   }

   public static int deleteName(Customer theArray[], int noOfElements) {
      String searchId;
      int step;
      int whichOne = 0;
      System.out.println("Enter Id of customer to be deleted ");
      searchId = EasyIn.getString();
      step = 0;
      while ((step < noOfElements)
            && !(theArray[step].getId().equals(searchId))) {
         step++;
      }
      if (step < noOfElements) {
         whichOne = step;
         for (step = whichOne; step < noOfElements - 1; step++) {
            theArray[step] = theArray[step + 1];
         }
         noOfElements--;
      } else {
         System.out.println(" Sorry this customer doesn't exist");
      }
      return noOfElements;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Customer empArray[];
      int index;
      int noOfElements;
      String searchName;
      Customer tempObject;
      int step;
      int option = 0;
      int place;
      String newName = "";
      String newId;
      int newBalance;
      int checkID = 0;
      empArray = new Customer[100000];
      noOfElements = 0;
      System.out
            .println("\n 1. Add Customer \n 2. Delete Customer \n 3. List all Customers \n 4. Exit");
      System.out.print("Enter Option ");
      option = EasyIn.getInt();
      while (option != 4) {
         if (option == 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter ID ");
            newId = EasyIn.getString();
            System.out.print("Enter name ");
            newName = EasyIn.getString();
            System.out.print("Enter Balance ");
            newBalance = EasyIn.getInt();
            System.out.println();
            tempObject = new Customer(newName, newId, newBalance);
            place = findPlace(empArray, newBalance, noOfElements);
            noOfElements = addOne(empArray, place, newId, tempObject,
                  noOfElements);
            checkID = checkId(empArray, noOfElements, newId);
            if (checkID == -1) {
               System.out.println("Sorry this ID already exists");
               checkID = 0;
            }
         } else if (option == 2) {
            noOfElements = deleteName(empArray, noOfElements);
         } else if (option == 3) {
            listAllNames(empArray, noOfElements);
         }
         System.out.print("Enter Option ");
         option = EasyIn.getInt();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the "bare minimum" that shows your problem and post it here. Otherwise you might receive more downvotes than useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

This effectively skips array entry at index 0:

```
while (step < noOfValues)
{

    step++;
```

Better:

```
public static int checkId(Customer theArray[], int noOfValues, String searchId){
    for (int step = 0; step < noOfValues; ++step ){
        if( theArray[step].getId().equals(searchId) )
        {
            return step;
        }   
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

Return -1 on not found, otherwise the index.

I haven't checked the remainder of your code, just saw that the use of an array  should be discarded in favour of a List.

Comment: Thank you so much Laune, upon slightly editing your given code, I managed to get it to work. Thanks for the help. Also thanks Hovercraft for the advice.